# Grant execute on all stored procedures using SSMS

Tags: sql-server

I have created a user with database roles `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter` and `public`. Also I have configured with server roles as `public`.

Now this user cannot view the list of stored procedure when clicking on stored procedures node in objects explorer. How can I assign permission to see and execute all the stored procedures? I want to do this through SSMS without launching any command.

I am using SQL Server 2012 and below versions:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.17763.1
Microsoft MSXML                                          3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.11.17763.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                                 4.0.30319.42000
Sistema operativo                                              6.3.17763
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not launching any command"? As in, not running any SQL? Impossible if so. Also, why are you still using SSMS 11? The latest version is now version 18.1 (though shows at 15 in the settings menu), and fully supports SQL Server 2012 .

Comment: please refer to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/grant-permissions-on-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I don't think SSMS has a way to grant execute permissions at the database level via Object Explorer. In an SSMS query window, you could run `GRANT EXECUTE ON DATABASE::YourDatabase TO YourUser;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you can do this, though not as "simple" as you would expect.

I would, personally create a database role to do this. Go to your database in the Object explorer, and expand the Security Folder. Then right click Roles and Select `New -> New Database Role`.

Give the Role a name (I'll use `db_executor`) on the General Pane and then go to the Securables Pane. Click `Search...` at the top and select the radio option `Specific Objects...` and click `OK`. Click `Object Types...` and then tick `Databases` and then `OK`. Now click `Browse...` and tick the database you are adding the role to, then click `OK` and then `OK`.

In the datagrid at the bottom locate the Permission `Execute`, and tick the box in the column `Grant`. Then `OK`. This will run the below SQL on your instance:

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO
CREATE ROLE [db_executor]
GO
use [YourDatabase]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE To [db_executor]
GO
```

*Yes, Microsoft really is inconsistent with the casing of `USE` for that statement, and it omits the `;` in it's commands.*

Now you have created the role, locate the user you want to give access to in the object explorer in the Users folder. Right Click them and select **`Properties`**. Go to the Membership Pane and tick the box next to `db_executor`. Then click `OK`. This will run the below SQL on your instance:

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_executor] ADD MEMBER [YourUser]
GO
```

Of course, why you wouldn't just run the 2 above commands, which is far quicker, I do not know.

Comment: Great explanation! Both answers are correct but I choose yours becasue you have explained it very detailed. Also you have explained how to do this by GUI and by T-SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a graphical way of doing this within the UI, but you can create a new query window in SSMS and execute one of these queries.

For a particular role you can:

```
/* GRANT EXECUTE TO THE ROLE */
GRANT EXECUTE TO role_what_needs_permissions
```

For a user

```
USE [the_database]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE TO [the_user]
```

Comment: ok, and using SQL Server Management Studio graphical interface?

Comment: You realise that the interface only runs SQL commands, right @user1624552?

Comment: Plus, as Jeff has said here, I don't think there is an option in the GUI, to run the command `GRANT EXECUTE TO {User/Role};` (I certainly can't find one). Why are you adverse to use SQL in SQL Server?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I know, but out of curisioty I would like to know how can I do the same using SSMS Graphical interface

Comment: @Larnu if you select the database, right-click and from the menu you select properties and then you go to permissions you can see a list of users, selecting user and check EXECUTE permission works, user can see now stored procedures and execute them.

Comment: @user1624552 there is no permissions pane on the User properties window. You have "General", "Owned Schemas", "Membership", "Securables" and "Extended properties"

Comment: I correct myself, you can do this in the GUI, but it's a lot of steps.

Comment: @Larnu I agree. Using GUI requires to do more steps.